# How to avoid outer list setting affect inner list list? What is the default setting of enumerate?

Tags: lists

For example,

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \begin{description}[leftmargin=2cm,labelindent=-0.25cm,labelsep*=1cm]
        \item[first] test
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item enumerate
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

the setting for description list is automatically inherited by nested enumerate list. But I don't want this way.

**So how to avoid outer list setting affecting inner list? or how to quickly make inner setting the default setting?**

What is the default setting of enumerate?

Comment: Use the `\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=...]` or the `\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=...}` feature (before `\begin{description}`. And consider first if you want to have this kind of nesting at all ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer so, just copy the setting in `description`? But I don't know the default setting of `enumerate`, how can I be able to write those settings?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What is the default setting of `enumerate`?